# preposition for tie

Tags: prepositions

is it correct using preposition (on) for the verb (tie)? when it is used with?
And do we use it when we want to use it for ( fastening to another thing)?
For example in this case:
" more and more travels; I tie on my sandals"

Comment: “I tie on my sandals” is not English, no. I’m not sure what it’s supposed to mean, even—do you mean that you _put on_ your sandals, or that you _tie_ your sandals _(on)to_ something else, like a backpack?

Comment: You might want to check out [ell.se]. [More here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).

Comment: "I tie on my sandals" is valid -- what is it? -- present perfect (?) English.  Doesn't particularly fit with "more and more travels", though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb.

Transitive use of verbs do not require being coupled to the subject via a preposition.

1. I killed the bug.
2. I eat dinner.
3. I am milking a cow.
4. I stopped to tie my shoes.

Potentially transitive verbs could of course be used non-transitively.

1. *I am shooting the deer*
   vs
   *I am shooting at the deer*
2. *She is eating her dog*
   vs
   *She is eating with her dog*
3. *They like eating chopsticks*
   vs
   *They like eating with chopsticks*

Do not mistake *prepositional phrasal verbs* with verb-preposition and verb-adverb phrases.

Words that are used as prepositions can also be used as adverbs. Do not mistake the prepositional use of a word with its adverbial use

#### Prepositional phrasal verbs

- She **takes after** her father.
  = 
  She behaves or is similar to her father.
- Did you **eat up** all the biscuits?
- You need to **tie up** your shoes.
- We shall **put on** some eye shadow.
- We need to **go over** the notes of the meeting.

#### Verb-adverb phrases

- Please don't **bring** the matter **up**.
- He has **turned** the lights **off**.
- When will that kid **put** her toys **away**?

#### Pidginization of verb-adverb phrases

into pseudo prepositional phrasal verbs

- Please don't **bring up** the matter.
- He has **turned off** the lights.
- When will that kid **put away** her toys?

#### Usual verb-preposition-subject coupling

due to intransitive use of a verb - and can be separated.

- She is **staying at** the hotel.
  **At** which hotel is she **staying**?
- These are the biscuits she has been **eating with** her dog.
  Which dog is she **eating** the biscuits **with**?
- Where is the meeting, to which I will be **going with** you?
  **With** whom am I **going** to the meeting?

#### *Prepositional phrasal verbs*-preposition-subject coupling

causing the confusion you are facing.

- She is ***putting up* at** the hotel.
  **At** which hotel is she ***putting up***?
- These are the biscuits she has been ***eating up* with** her dog.
  **With** whose dog has she been ***eating up*** the biscuits?
- Where are the notes of the meeting that I will be ***going over* with** you?
  **With** whom should I ***go over*** the notes?

Answer (score 2):

That is alright as far as it goes.

But in different contexts *tie* can take *to, with, by, in, from, up* and I have no doubt others.

*The rope was tied to posts to form a boundary*.

*The parcel was tied with strong string*.

*The prisoners were tied by their wrists*.

*The participants in the three-legged race were tied in pairs*

*The equipment was tied from the rafters when not in use*.

*The bundle was tied up securely*

Comment: Some naughty person might add _The scores were tied after seven rounds._

Comment: Or "tied as before"!